# No tests found to run using selenium when i click run test

Tags: c#, selenium

when i click  run test 
this is the message "No tests found to run"
this is image with my  code and error

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZemc.png][1]

Comment: Please tag your question with the language your using to implement your Selenium tests. Also, say where you're clicking Run - Eclipse, IntelliJ, Visual Studio etc. Inserting that information will help you to get some help.

Comment: Ok @Tom Like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is not marked as public. Try that.

```
public class ClsPlacements
```